How do I change battery charge thresholds (on a newer ThinkPad model)?
I'm trying to conserve my new laptop's battery for many years to come. Can you help me set this up optimally (probably a way to have it automatically stop charging the battery after it reaches some value between 60 to 85%)?
I have read a fair bit about tlp, tp-smapi, and tpacti-bat online, but end up being more confused about it than understanding which one is best for a newer machine (most posts and comments I've read are ~8 years old); and how to install and configure the battery with whichever one is best.
Thank you in advance! Here is information regarding my setup  :-)

OS: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Model: Lenovo ThinkPad X13 Gen 4
Processor: AMD Ryzen™ 7 PRO 7840U
Kernal: Linux 6.8.0-31-generic

(It's probably unnecessary, but in the terminal, the command lsmod yields:
...:~$ lsmod 

Module                  Size  Used by

ccm                    20480  6

michael_mic            12288  1

rfcomm                 98304  4

snd_seq_dummy          12288  0

snd_hrtimer            12288  1

snd_seq_midi           24576  0

snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi

snd_rawmidi            57344  1 snd_seq_midi

snd_seq               118784  9 
snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_dummy

snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi

cmac                   12288  3

algif_hash             12288  1

algif_skcipher         16384  1

af_alg                 32768  6 algif_hash,algif_skcipher

bnep                   32768  2

qrtr_mhi               16384  0

binfmt_misc            24576  1

nls_iso8859_1          12288  2

amdgpu              17088512  9

snd_acp6x_pdm_dma      12288  0

snd_soc_dmic           12288  0

snd_soc_acp6x_mach     28672  0

snd_sof_amd_acp63      16384  0

snd_sof_amd_vangogh    16384  0

snd_sof_amd_rembrandt    16384  0

snd_sof_amd_renoir     16384  0

snd_sof_amd_acp        61440  4 

snd_sof_amd_rembrandt,snd_sof_amd_vangogh,snd_sof_amd_acp63,snd_sof_amd
_renoir

snd_sof_pci            24576  4 
snd_sof_amd_rembrandt,snd_sof_amd_vangogh,snd_sof_amd_acp63,snd_sof_amd_renoir

snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     12288  1 snd_sof_amd_acp

snd_sof               380928  2 snd_sof_amd_acp,snd_sof_pci

snd_ctl_led            24576  0

snd_sof_utils          16384  1 snd_sof

snd_hda_codec_realtek   200704  1

snd_soc_core          454656  4 
snd_soc_acp6x_mach,snd_sof,snd_acp6x_pdm_dma,snd_soc_dmic

snd_hda_codec_generic   122880  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek

snd_compress           28672  1 snd_soc_core

snd_hda_codec_hdmi     94208  1

amdxcp                 12288  1 amdgpu

btusb                  77824  0

ac97_bus               12288  1 snd_soc_core

drm_exec               16384  1 amdgpu

btrtl                  36864  1 btusb

snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core

gpu_sched              61440  1 amdgpu

snd_pci_ps             24576  0

snd_hda_intel          61440  2

uvcvideo              139264  0

btintel                57344  1 btusb

drm_buddy              20480  1 amdgpu

snd_rpl_pci_acp6x      16384  0

snd_intel_dspcfg       36864  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof

videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo

btbcm                  24576  1 btusb

drm_suballoc_helper    16384  1 amdgpu

snd_acp_pci            12288  0

snd_intel_sdw_acpi     16384  1 snd_intel_dspcfg

uvc                    12288  1 uvcvideo

btmtk                  16384  1 btusb

drm_ttm_helper         12288  1 amdgpu

snd_acp_legacy_common    16384  1 snd_acp_pci

videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc

snd_hda_codec         217088  4 
snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_re
altek

ttm                   110592  2 amdgpu,drm_ttm_helper

videobuf2_v4l2         40960  1 uvcvideo

bluetooth            1089536  34 
btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm

snd_pci_acp6x          16384  0

snd_hda_core          151552  5 
snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,sn
d_hda_codec_realtek

drm_display_helper    253952  1 amdgpu

snd_pci_acp5x          16384  0

videodev              364544  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo

snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec

cec                    98304  1 drm_display_helper

snd_rn_pci_acp3x       16384  0

ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth

videobuf2_common       86016  4 
videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_memops

snd_acp_config         20480  9 
snd_rn_pci_acp3x,snd_pci_acp6x,snd_pci_acp5x,snd_sof_amd_rembrandt,snd_
sof_amd_vangogh,snd_sof_amd_acp63,snd_acp_pci,snd_pci_ps,snd_sof_amd_re
noir

rc_core                77824  1 cec

snd_pcm               200704  13 
snd_sof_amd_acp,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pci_acp6x,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_
codec,snd_sof,snd_acp6x_pdm_dma,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_sof_utils
,snd_hda_core,snd_pci_ps,snd_pcm_dmaengine

ecc                    45056  1 ecdh_generic

usbhid                 77824  0

mc                     86016  4 
videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common

snd_soc_acpi           20480  2 snd_sof_amd_acp,snd_acp_config

i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 amdgpu

snd_pci_acp3x          16384  0

snd_timer              49152  3 snd_seq,snd_hrtimer,snd_pcm

intel_rapl_msr         20480  0

intel_rapl_common      40960  1 intel_rapl_msr

edac_mce_amd           28672  0

kvm_amd               208896  0

ccp                   143360  1 kvm_amd

qrtr                   53248  7 qrtr_mhi

ath11k_pci             32768  0

kvm                  1437696  1 kvm_amd

ath11k                868352  1 ath11k_pci

irqbypass              12288  1 kvm

crct10dif_pclmul       12288  1

qmi_helpers            32768  1 ath11k

polyval_clmulni        12288  0

polyval_generic        12288  1 polyval_clmulni

ses                    20480  0

ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0

enclosure              24576  1 ses

mac80211             1728512  1 ath11k

sha256_ssse3           32768  0

scsi_transport_sas     57344  1 ses

sha1_ssse3             32768  0

aesni_intel           356352  8

crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel

cryptd                 28672  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel

cfg80211             1339392  2 ath11k,mac80211

uas                    28672  1

usb_storage            90112  1 uas

rapl                   20480  0

libarc4                12288  1 mac80211

think_lmi              45056  0

firmware_attributes_class    12288  1 think_lmi

thinkpad_acpi         163840  0

wmi_bmof               12288  0

mhi                   106496  2 ath11k_pci,qrtr_mhi

k10temp                16384  0

i2c_piix4              32768  0

nvram                  16384  1 thinkpad_acpi

amd_pmc                45056  0

input_leds             12288  0

joydev                 32768  0

serio_raw              20480  0

mac_hid                12288  0

msr                    12288  0

parport_pc             53248  0

ppdev                  24576  0

lp                     28672  0

parport                77824  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev

efi_pstore             12288  0

nfnetlink              20480  1

dmi_sysfs              24576  0

ip_tables              36864  0

x_tables               69632  1 ip_tables

autofs4                57344  2

nvme                   61440  2

hid_multitouch         36864  0

ucsi_acpi              12288  0

snd                   147456  22 
snd_ctl_led,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_
hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_so
f,snd_timer,snd_compress,thinkpad_acpi,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi

nvme_core             212992  3 nvme

hid_generic            12288  0

typec_ucsi             61440  1 ucsi_acpi

soundcore              16384  2 snd_ctl_led,snd

xhci_pci               24576  0

video                  73728  2 thinkpad_acpi,amdgpu

crc32_pclmul           12288  0

ledtrig_audio          12288  2 snd_ctl_led,thinkpad_acpi

psmouse               217088  0

thunderbolt           512000  0

xhci_pci_renesas       20480  1 xhci_pci

i2c_hid_acpi           12288  0

nvme_auth              28672  1 nvme_core

typec                 110592  1 typec_ucsi

platform_profile       12288  1 thinkpad_acpi

i2c_hid                40960  1 i2c_hid_acpi

wmi                    32768  3 video,wmi_bmof,think_lmi

hid                   184320  4 
i2c_hid,usbhid,hid_multitouch,hid_generic

)

All out-of-tree kernel module stuff e.g. tp-smapi, acpi_call, tpacpi-bat is obsolete for your model and kernel.
Just install the package tlp and configure charge thresholds by uncommenting and editing the corresponding lines in /etc/tlp.conf:
START_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0=60
STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0=85

Then activate the new thresholds via the command line
sudo tlp setcharge

and check the result with
sudo tlp-stat -b

Instead of any googled reading from the Linux stone age, I recommend the up-to-date official documentation for TLP:

https://linrunner.de/tlp/settings/battery.html
https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/battery.html#which-external-kernel-module-do-i-need-for-my-thinkpad
https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/battery.html#how-to-choose-good-battery-charge-thresholds


Here is a bash script that will notify you whenever the charge is above 80%:
#!/bin/bash
battery_percentage=$(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 | grep -E 'percentage' | grep -o -E '[0-9]+')

echo $battery_percentage

if [ $battery_percentage -gt 60 ]; then
  notify-send "Battery Above 80%"
fi

You can add it to systemd as a daemon and it'll notify you whenever the battery is above 80%.
The only requirement is libnotify that can be installed with this command:
sudo apt install libnotify4


Thanks! This is great. I have been assuming there is a way to stop the charging, but don't have any reason for this. If you come across a more automatic way to accomplish charging cessation, please feel free to let me know--I'll upgrade the solution from great to perfect.

You're welcome @dcpetit, linrunner's answer is exactly what you're looking for, mine just notifies.
